# Form is submitting if condition fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to submit a form where it has to submit if condition is satisfied, else the form should not get submitted. The form is getting submitted for both the condition else not submitting for both the conditions.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
           //$('#student').change(function() { 
          $('#but').click(function() { 
          var payid = $("#feType").val();
          var course = $("#course").val();
          var course_id = $("#course_id").val();
          var stud_id = $("#student").val();
          var paid_amt1 = $("#paid_amt").val();

          var serializedData = $("form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '<?php echo ADMINPATH;?>student/getNewFee/'+payid+'/'+course_id+'/'+stud_id+'/'+course,
                    data: '',
                    async: true,                    
                    success: function(data){

                      if(data == false){
                         $("form").unbind('submit').submit();
                         alert("This student doesn't have transport");
                         return false;
                      }
                      var result = data; 

                      if(Number(result) >= Number(paid_amt1)){
                        $("#fee_data").submit(function(){
                          return true;
                        });    
                      }else {
                        $("form").unbind('submit');
                          alert("Due Amount is less than paid amount");
                          return false;        
                      }
                   }      
             });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: To prevent the form submitting, attach as an event handler to the form (`onsubmit`) not the button.

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact Behaviour of your case?? what do you enter as values, and does the Alerts Show??
perhaps all you need to do is put your code in a $(document).ready block, so it'll be something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: I kept that code, yet the form is getting submitted, I want the form to be stopped from submitting when it comes to else condition

Comment: try to change the button type from "Submit" to "button", in its click handler js function, test your condition(s), if true, perform the submission..
(Again I assumed that you have a button of type submit, if not please edit your question to include the form's html)